# need to query work items related to release in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have recently started using TFS for deploying release tickets, i was trying to check to see the number of workitems related to each release# but there is no easy way of finding it, any suggestions?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the vNext build, you can use the REST API to get the number of workitems related to each release.

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/workitems
```

You can use below PowerShell script to achieve that:

---

```
#Get the work items associated to Release

$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/Collection"
$project = "ProjectName"

$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

#Get releases
$baseReleasesUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/release/releases"
$Releases = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseReleasesUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential

#Get the associated work items.
foreach ($release in $Releases.value)
{
$releaseID = $release.id
$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/release/releases/$releaseID/workitems"            
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential
$wits = $response.value

Write-Host "Release name:" $release.name
Write-Host "Release ID  :" $release.id
Write-Host "Count of Asssociated Work items:"$response.count

      foreach ($wit in $wits)
    {
      Write-Host "Work item ID:" $wit.id
    }
    write-host 

}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea if this is available for VSTS?